# Numeric example for domain of scaled function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Suppose the function $f(x)$ is defined on the domain $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, so that the graph of $y=f(x)$ consists of just three points. Suppose those three points form a triangle of area $32$.

The graph of $y = 2f(2x)$ also consists of just three points. What is the area of the triangle formed by those three points?

I have been told that $y = 2f(2x)$ has domain $\{x_1/2,x_2/2,x_3/2\}$. I am trying to work this out with a numeric example. Can anyone help?

For example: f(x) had domain {3, 6, 7}.
Then, f(2x) would take inputs 6, 12, and 14. Then, why is it getting divided by 2.

Comment: No, $f(2x)$ would take inputs $3/2$, $3$, and $7/2$.

Comment: Thanks. If you make an answer out of this, then I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f(2x)$ would take inputs $3/2,3$, and $7/2$.